# Change date format

Tags: shell-script, aix

Given a string which contains a date as a substring, how can I convert that substring from one date-format to another? More specifically, I have the following questions:

1. How can I convert the date-string "10/24/2017 8:00:00 AM" to the date-string "20171024 8:00:00 AM"?
2. How can I convert "Data1|Data2|Data3|10/24/2017 8:00:00 AM" to "Data1|Data2|Data3|20171024 8:00:00 AM"?
3. If I have a file called "Sample.csv" containing lines of this form (i.e. pipe-delimited data), how can I convert the date in each line of "Sample.csv" (as in the previous question)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `date` command you're looking for:

```
date -d '${DATE_STRING}' '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %p'
```

The `-d` (equivalently `--date`) flag is used to specify a string representing the date/time input. The manual has this to say about it:

> DATE STRING
>
> The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800"  or  "2004-02-29  16:21:42"  or  even "next  Thursday".   A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning of the day.  The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here  but  is  fully described in the info documentation.

With the date string given in your post the above example would look like this:

```
date -d '10/24/2017 8:00:00 AM' '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %p'
```

If you want to extract the date from the full string in the example that you've given, then you might do this:

```
DATE_STRING="Data1|Data2|Data3|10/24/2017 8:00:00 AM"
date -d "$(echo "${DATE_STRING}" | cut -d'|' -f4)" '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %p'
```

To achieve the desired final result for a single string you could do something like the following:

```
DATE_STRING="Data1|Data2|Data3|10/24/2017 8:00:00 AM"
echo "$(echo "${DATE_STRING}" | cut -d'|' -f1,2,3)|$(date -d "$(echo "${DATE_STRING}" | cut -d'|' -f4)" '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %p')"
```

And finally, to run this command on every line in the file you could do something like this:

```
while read line; do echo "$(echo "${DATE_STRING}" | cut -d'|' -f1,2,3)|$(date -d "$(echo "${DATE_STRING}" | cut -d'|' -f4)" '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %p')"; done < Sample.csv
```